# Nested loop in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am a beginner at shell programming. I have a problem related to nested loops in shell scripts. I want to get output like this:

Input: `4`

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
```

This is the script I am using so far:

```
echo "input : "
read a
for ((i=0; i<a; i++))
do
   for ((j=0; j<i; j++))
   do
       echo "*"
   done
   echo "\n"
done
```

When trying to execute my program I get an error: `Bad for looping`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
echo "input : "
read a
for ((i=0; i<a; i++))
do
   for ((j=0; j<=i; j++))
   do
       printf "*"
   done
   echo
done
```

To not print newlines, you can use `printf` (or the echo -n but is not as portable as `printf`)

Comment: thanks you for advance. are u prefer printf than echo in shell scripting?

Comment: Actually, it depends on individuals. If I am not writing portable scripts, i just use `echo` for simple display. if i want string formatting, i use `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get any error with the script! Though the echo needs to be different like below:

```
echo "input : "
read a
for ((i=0; i<a; i++))
do
   for ((j=0; j<i; j++))
   do
       echo -ne "*"
   done
   echo -ne "\n"
done
```

You might try adding $ in front of the variables while accessing them though. 
It is not giving any errors for me.

Comment: `echo -e "\n"` will print 2 new lines, `echo -e ""` is good enough.

Comment: @anubhava - right edited to `echo -ne "\n"` to make it consistent and clearly convey the newline meaning

Comment: @manojids, just `echo ` will provide the same output as `echo -ne "\n"`

Comment: @ghostdog74 - I have explained in my comment above that it is to convey the newline in echo more clearly since obviously the OP was not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

print_starry_row()
{
    n="$1"
    for ((i=0;i<n;i++))
    {
        echo -n "*"
    }
    echo
}

read -p "Enter number of stars? " num

if [[ "$num" -eq $num ]]
then
    for ((i=1;i<=num;i++))
    {
        print_starry_row $i
    }
else
    echo "You must enter a valid integrer"
fi
```